# Azure KeyVault nuget package issues

Tags: azure, .net-core, nuget, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

When I installing Azure.KeyVault package version 3 alpha, I'm getting the following runtime exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Could not find or load a specific file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131621)
```

Downgrading this package to latest stable 2.3.2 causes another error:

[image]

Here is my package list with dependencies:

[image]

Any ideas or workaround on this?

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2786

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem was inside v2 runtime:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2854

My decision was to turn roll back to v1 Functions, cause I found another issues during the KeyVault implementation by this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-managed-service-identity

Here is the issue:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2852